# ASP file, but need to display different urls per organization

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

***EDIT***
Ok, so in the files code, which is the file that it goes to after you click on the Search button, there is the following code:

```
<%
    Dim DbConnectionStr
    Dim objConn
    Dim OrgRS, SQL
    Dim StateRS, SQL1

    TempOrganization = Request.Form("Organization")
    TempState = Request.Form("State")
    TempOrgType = Request.Form("OrgType")
    TempLenderType = Trim(Request.Form("LenderType"))
    TempAttributes = Request.Form("Attributes")
    TempAreaServed = Request.Form("AreaServed")
    'response.Write TempAreaServed
    DbConnectionStr = Database Password Information....(Not listed, unimportant for you to help me with)
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open DbConnectionStr     

    SQL = "Select * FROM CDFILocator"

    WhereFlag = False
    DisplayFlag = False
    DisplayCriteria = ""

    If TempOrganization <> "ALL" then
        SQL = SQL & " WHERE OrganizationName = '" & TempOrganization & "'"
        DisplayCriteria = "Organization Name is <b>" & TempOrganization & "</b>"
        WhereFlag = True
    Else
        DisplayCriteria = "Any Organization"
        DisplayFlag = True 
    End If  

    If TempState <> "ALL" then
        If WhereFlag = False then
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE State = '" & TempState & "'"
            DisplayCriteria = "State is <b>" & TempState & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        Else
            SQL = SQL & " and State = '" & TempState & "'"
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and State is <b>" & TempState & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        End If  
    Else
        If WhereFlag = False and DisplayFlag = False then
            DisplayCriteria = "Any State" 
            DisplayFlag = True
        Else
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Any State"
        End If      
    End If  


    If TempAreaServed <> "ALL" then
        arrAreaServed = Split(TempAreaServed, ", ", -1, 1)
        If WhereFlag = False then
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE ("'" & TempAreaServed & "')"
            DisplayCriteria = "Area(s) Served: "  
            For I = LBound(arrAreaServed) To UBound(arrAreaServed)
                SQL = SQL & "AreaServed like '%" & arrAreaServed(I) & "%' or "
                DisplayCriteria = DisplayCriteria & arrAreaServed(I) & ","
            Next
            DisplayCriteria = Mid(DisplayCriteria,1,Len(DisplayCriteria)-1)
            ' Add National for all
            SQL = SQL & "AreaServed like '%national%' or "
            SQL = Mid(SQL,1,Len(SQL)-3)
            SQL = SQL & ")"
            WhereFlag = True
        Else
            SQL = SQL & " AND ("'" & TempAreaServed & "')"
            DisplayCriteria = DisplayCriteria & " and Area(s) Served: "  
            For I = LBound(arrAreaServed) To UBound(arrAreaServed)
                SQL = SQL & "AreaServed like '%" & arrAreaServed(I) & "%' or "
                DisplayCriteria = DisplayCriteria & arrAreaServed(I) & ","
            Next
            DisplayCriteria = Mid(DisplayCriteria,1,Len(DisplayCriteria)-1)
            ' Add National for all
            SQL = SQL & "AreaServed like '%national%' or "
            SQL = Mid(SQL,1,Len(SQL)-3)
            SQL = SQL & ")"
            WhereFlag = True
        End If
    Else
        If WhereFlag = False and DisplayFlag = False then
            DisplayCriteria = "Any Area Served in the Nation" 
            DisplayFlag = True
        Else
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Any Area Served in the Nation"
        End If      
    End If  
    If TempOrgType <> "ALL" then
        If WhereFlag = False then
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE OrganizationType like '%" & TempOrgType & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria = "Organization Type is <b>" & TempOrgType & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        Else
            SQL = SQL & " and OrganizationType like '%" & TempOrgType & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Organization Type is <b>" & TempOrgType & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        End If  
    Else
        If WhereFlag = False and DisplayFlag = False then
            DisplayCriteria = "Any Organization Type"
            DisplayFlag = True 
        Else
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Any Organization Type"
        End If      
    End If  

    If TempLenderType <> "ALL" then
        If WhereFlag = False then
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE LendingType like '%" & TempLenderType & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria = "Lending Type is <b>" & TempLenderType & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        Else
            SQL = SQL & " and LendingType like '%" & TempLenderType & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Lending Type is <b>" & TempLenderType & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        End If  
    Else
        If WhereFlag = False and DisplayFlag = False then
            DisplayCriteria = "Any Lender Type"
            DisplayFlag = True 
        Else
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Any Lender Type"
        End If      
    End If  

    If TempAttributes <> "ALL" then
        If WhereFlag = False then
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE Attributes like '%" & TempAttributes & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria = "Attributes are <b>" & TempAttributes & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        Else
            SQL = SQL & " and Attributes like '%" & TempAttributes & "%'"
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Attributes are <b>" & TempAttributes & "</b>"
            WhereFlag = True
        End If  
    Else
        If WhereFlag = False and DisplayFlag = False then
            DisplayCriteria = "Any Attributes"
            DisplayFlag = True 
        Else
            DisplayCriteria =  DisplayCriteria & " and Any Attributes"
        End If      
    End If  

    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY OrganizationName"

    'Response.Write SQL

    Set OrgRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    OrgRS.Open SQL,objConn,adOpenKeySet,3

    TempRecordCount = OrgRS.RecordCount


%>
<% 
Dim strAryUrl
Dim strValue
Dim textSelection

strValue = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
strAryUrl = Split(strValue, "/")  

%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Opportunity Finance Network, Mark Pinsky, community, development, community development, community development bank, community development fund, community development financial institution, community investment, affordable housing, urban renewal, loan fund, credit union, bank, banking, finance, financial, financing, funding, investing, loan, loans, microenterprise, venture capital, venture capital fund, CDFI, CDFIs, housing, business, small business, local business, community facilities, consumer financial services, socially responsible investing, socially responsible investment, community investing, revitalization, social justice, economic justice, economically-disadvantaged">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/OFNStyles.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/navigation.css" type="text/css" />

<title>Opportunity Finance Network - Industry</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/inc/mainNavigation.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
body{behavior:url(/css_hover.htc);}
#menu a, #menu h2{font:bold 0.7em/1.4em arial,helvetica,sans-serif;}
#menu ul li{float:left;height:1%;width:100%;}
#menu ul li a{height:1%;}
</style>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <table width="680" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top" bgcolor="#072A60" height="24"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <center>
            <a href="/default.aspx"><img src="/images/ofnHeader.png" title="Home" width="680" height="71"  border="0" alt="Opportunity Finance Network" /></a>
        </center>

        <!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/inc/mainNav.inc" -->

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><table width="680" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mainTable">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" id="leftNav" nowrap="nowrap">
            <!-- #include file="subNav.inc" -->
            <!-- #include virtual="/subNavPromos/subNavPromos.inc" -->                       
          </td>
          <td valign="top" id="mainCont" class="bodytxt">
          <a style="float: right;text-decoration: underline;" href="/industry/industry_locator.asp">Search Again</a> 

<style type="text/css">
.MPimgs { float: right; }
.MPlogo { text-align: right; float: right; }
.attribute { clear: right; float: right; margin-top: 5px; }
.MPdetails { line-height: 1.5; }
.ie6 .MPdetails,
.ie6 .MPimgs  { float: right; }
.ie6 .MPdetails { width: 234px; }
.ie6 .MPimgs { width: 200px; }
.ie6 .attribute { clear: right; }
.ie6 hr { clear: right; }
</style>

<h1>Find a CDFI Results</h1>

<p><strong>Search Criteria</strong>: <%=DisplayCriteria%>.</p> 

<%  If Not OrgRS.EOF then

        While not OrgRS.EOF %>

    <h4><%=ORgRS("OrganizationName")%></h4>

        <div class="MPimgs">
        <% If Len(Trim(ORgRS("ImageFile"))) > 0 then %>
            <img  class="MPlogo" src="../images/members/<%=ORgRS("ImageFile")%>" border="0">
        <% End If %>

            <!-- Insert WNA Images here -->

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "CARS Rated") then %>
            <br /><a href="http://www.carsratingsystem.net"><img class="attribute" src="../images/cars_rated.gif" alt="CARS&trade; Rated" border="0" /></a>
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "10awardee") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/10awardee.png" alt="10 WNA Awardee" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "10finalist") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/10finalist.png" alt="10 WNA Finalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "10semi") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/10semi-finalist.png" alt="10 WNA SemiFinalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "09awardee") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/09awardee.png" alt="09 WNA Awardee" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "09finalist") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/09finalist.png" alt="09 WNA Finalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "09semi") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/09semi-finalist.png" alt="09 WNA SemiFinalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "08awardee") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/08awardee.png" alt="08 WNA Awardee" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "08finalist") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/08finalist.png" alt="08 WNA Finalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "08semi") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/08semi-finalist.png" alt="08 WNA Semifinalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "07awardee") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/07awardee.png" alt="07 WNA Awardee" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "07finalist") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/07finalist.png" alt="07 WNA Finalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "07semi") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/07semi-finalist.png" alt="07 WNA Semifinalist" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

        <% If Len(Trim(ORgRS("MemberProfile"))) > 0 then %>
            <br /><b><a class="attribute" href="../store/Downloads/<%=ORgRS("MemberProfile")%>" target="_blank"><img class="attribute" src="../images/mpDownload.png" alt="Download Member Profile" border="0" /></a></b>
        <% End If %>

        <% If Instr(ORgRS("Attributes"), "CJ4USA") then %>
            <br /><img class="attribute" src="../images/cj4usaAwardee.png" alt="Create Jobs for USA Awardee" border="0" />
        <% End If %>

     </div> <!-- End MPimgs -->     


          <p class="MPdetails"><%=ORgRS("Address1")%><br />
          <% If ORgRS("Address2") <> "" then %>
            <%=ORgRS("Address2")%><br />
          <% Else %>
          <% End If %>
          <%=ORgRS("City")%>,&nbsp;<%=ORgRS("State")%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=ORgRS("ZipCode")%> <br />
          <b>Phone:</b> <%=ORgRS("Phone")%><br />
          <b>Fax:</b> <%=ORgRS("Fax")%><br />
          <b>E-Mail:</b> <a href="Mailto:<%=ORgRS("EMail")%>"><%=ORgRS("EMail")%></a><br />
          <b>URL:</b> <a href="<%=ORgRS("URL")%>" target="_blank"><% If Len(Trim(ORgRS("URL"))) > 50 then %><%=Mid(ORgRS("URL"),1,50)%>...<% Else %><%=ORgRS("URL")%><% End If %></a><br />
          <b>Contact Person:</b> <%=ORgRS("ContactPerson")%>, <%=ORgRS("Title")%><br />
          <b>Area Served:</b> <%=ORgRS("AreaServed")%><br />
          <b>Organization Type:</b> <%=ORgRS("OrganizationType")%><br />
          <b>Lending Type:</b> <%=ORgRS("LendingType")%></p>

          <p><%=ORgRS("Description")%></p>


            <hr color="Black" width="50%" Align="center">
<%      OrgRS.MoveNext
        Wend
%>
            <p class="bodytxt" style="float: right;"><a href="/industry/industry_locator.asp">Search Again</a></p>
<%      
    Else    
%>                  
          <p class="bodytxt">No results found from your search criteria.</p> 
          <p class="bodytxt"><a href="/industry/industry_locator.asp">Search Again</a></p> 

<%  End If %>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="footCell">

      <!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/inc/footer.inc" -->

<!-- Start Google Analytics Code  -->
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-965748-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics Code  --></body>
</html>

<%  OrgRS.Close
    Set OrgRS = nothing
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = nothing
%>
```

Let me know if you will need anymore code.  What I need to do is just get the information from the database based on the URL somehow...

Comment: Only someone who knows about this industry_locator.asp could answer your question.

Comment: Should I post up the code from the industry_locator.asp file?  Would that help any?

Comment: How much code is it? You may have to actually try to solve this problem yourself, then come back here when you have a problem with that. Right now, you're pretty much asking us to solve your problem for you.

Comment: If this is production code you should seriously take it offline immediately. It is at least vulnerable to SQL injection and cross site scripting (XSS) attacks. Please don't put your visitors at risk!

Comment: This is the code that I came into.  It is not my code!  Honestly, what changes would you suggest?  I'm all ears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since URL mapping or static pages requires more work, I recommend query string on your URL as follow:

`http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/?{organizations name}`

Read the query string and show the appropriate result. Since currently the mentioned page address doesn't change, it posts data to itself. So if code be available to us, it's easy to tell you which lines of code are responsible for fetching data (post your code here for more help)

**UPDATE:**

If URL syntax be: `http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/?organization={organizations name}`

Then replace the line `TempOrganization = Request.Form("Organization")` with following:

> TempOrganization = Request("Organization")

Comment: Ok, I have posted up the code from the industry_locator_proc.asp file which is responsible for outputting the organization information from the database and into the page.  But this uses a Form Request from the previous page.  I just need to be able to grab it from the `Request.ServerVariables("URL")`, so that if `?{organizations name} exists, to get that name and use that for the Database query to output the information on the page... But how?

Comment: If I have to write a whole new file for doing this, that would be fine also... since the `industry_locator_proc.asp` file is linking to the form on `industry_locator.asp`, but whatever you think is best really.  And if I should create a new file for doing this, perhaps you could get me started in how to go about doing it??  Thanks a million!!!

Comment: @SolomonClosson: You need to hit `If TempOrgType <> "ALL" then` condition as it is doing now whenever your `URL` has the appropriate query string. Just set `TempOrganization` according to query string at the top of code, it hits the condition automatically. Just one line changes.

Comment: How to do that??  Can you please help me?

Comment: How can I find out if the URL has that in it??

Comment: Using `Request("Organization")` reads `Organization` variable from POST or GET (URL or FORM) so just replace `Request.Form("Organization")` with `Request("Organization")` as mentioned in UPDATED Answer by me and use provided URL syntax for testing the result.

Comment: `If (InStr(strValue, "?organization=") > 0) then
  TempOrganization = Request("organization")
 Else
  TempOrganization = Request.Form("Organization")
 End If`  I have tried this, but it doesn't work!!!

Comment: Ok, I just replaced it... but now when I type in a organization name... url as follows:  http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/industry_locator_proc.asp?Organization=3CORE it says, NO RESULTS FOUND, but it does show the Name of the Organization atleast now...

Comment: You don't need to check `"?organization="` ASP handles it. Just do as updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I did as your updated answer suggests...  Go to this link, and you will see what happens:  http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/industry_locator_proc.asp?Organization=3CORE  Nothing gets outputted, cept the Name of the organization...  I think I need to set all of the other values to "ALL", but how?  And also, I will need to account for organizations that have spaces in their name.

Comment: I guess that is because your code needs some other variables like `TempState` or `TempAttributes`... set them to default values. Remember we are trying to mimic what was already acceptable by posting the form so if some default values are send by POST, we need them in GET scenario. Coder didn't expect this behavior so maybe he is checking somewhere for other variables and finding them empty caused the situation.

Comment: If there is any SPACE in name just use `%20` in URL i.g. `http://sample.com?q=FirstName%20LastName`. This would be read at server side as `strVal = FirstName LastName`

Comment: WOW, you ROCK BRO!!!  WE DID IT!!  It works now!!!  Thanks sooo very much!  I would like to change the `%20` to just use this character instead `_` BUT WHATEVER!!!  THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't like `%20` just replace all `_` with SPACE as server side. Make sure there are no `_` already in names. Also test POST behavior, maybe setting default values is not in good order.

Comment: Nope, works great, cause I did a test to see if the `TempOrganization=""`, than I do `Request.QueryString("Organization")` Also, with this check, I can get rid of the Search-related stuff on that page, and just show Organization Related information!!!  YAYY!!!

Answer (score 0):

if instead of this url

```
http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/{organizations name}
```

you can change to to

```
http://opportunityfinance.net/industry#{organizations name}
```

then you would be able to handle everything client side

read the hash tag value by `window.location.hash` and then change the value of the Organizations Dropdown and programmatically click the button to load the info

Comment: What file should I be adding `window.location.hash` to, in order to read the hash tag value?

Comment: In the file is seems to be grabbing information from the database in tags that are as follows:  `<%` and `%>`, in the industry_locator_proc.asp file, it seems to be using a lot of these tags, before the document is even written.  Should I just create my own .asp file for this?

Comment: Ok, well after reviewing this in more depth, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass the `location.hash` from Javascript into an ASP variable that I could use to grab the information from the database.  Any ideas??

Comment: you cannot send the hash variable to the server side.

Comment: what im saying here is that because all your page is already set up to display the organization content without changing the url.. what you can do is just add a hash pamameter for each organization and then when the page loads in the javascript check the value of the hash param and do this things programmatically that are done when the user selects an organization